# nested tag rails issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

I don't understand this output. I have this

```
<%= link_to(:class=>"dropdown-toggle", "data-toggle"=> "dropdown") do %>
    <%= content_tag(:span, :class=>"hidden-xs-only") do %>
        <%= link_to("Sign Up", new_user_registration_path) %>
    <% end %>
<% end%>
```

but it outputs this

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="hidden-xs-only">
    </span>
</a>
<a href="/users/sign_up">Sign Up</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, nesting `<a>` tags is not valid HTML.

Use a `<ul>` or `<div>` for the outer element

---

You'd have to use javascript to toggle the child elements anyway, so yes, just add an `onclick` listener with a function that displays/hides the dropdown

Comment: so how can I put link on that ? should I use some javascript ?

Comment: Yes. It's likely that your Rails application spits out the HTML you expect but your browser (depending on what you use) tries to make the most of what it considers invalid HTML and ends up with that.

Comment: For Bootstrap, single items having structure `DIV > (A + (UL > LI > A structure))`: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage And this one for navs, which has structure `UL > LI > (A + (inner UL > LI > A structure))`: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-dropdowns